# rewrite rules - help to write it

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my web site placed at:
www.mywebsite.it/folder

I have installed `qTranslate` plugin so I have:

```
www.mywebsite.it/folder/en
www.mywebsite.it/folder/it
```

I would remove the folder string from urls.

How can I do it?
Thanks a lot.

My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: No rewrite rule needed — Move the files outside of the folder? Not sure if I get you right.

Comment: no i need some rules because the wordpress installation is one and stored in folder. With the qtranslate plugin I have en and it version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `.htaccess` file in the document root of `www.mywebsite.it`.
Try these rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(en|it)/(.*)$ /folder/$1/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```